# iOS ACAccountStore Facebook token type?

Tags: ios, facebook-access-token, social-framework, acaccountstore

With reference to this: [Generating Long-Lived User Tokens from Server-Side Long-Lived Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#long-via-code)

Does iOS's ACAccountStore returns a long-lived or short-lived access token?

And how does setting `Single Sign On` on, in the Facebook app affect the token?

I plan to store the retrieved access token from mobile on my server as authentication for users who sign up with FB. So I'll need a long-lived access token.

Also I plan to use Social Framework instead of Facebook SDK.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where this is documented or how it is affected by Single Sign On (if at all), but I just created a new token with and fed it into the [Facebook Access Token Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken) and it reported that the the token expired in 2 months which, according to the document you linked, makes it a **long-lived user token**.